# Does changing the Kafka-streams topology( adding a repartition step) has any effect on message processing guarantee

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say I want to make some transformation 'A' configurable. This transformation manages some state using state-store and also requires **repartitioning**, which means repartitioning will be done only if  configured. Now if I run the application 3 times (may be rolling upgrade as well) in following way (or any other combination) :-

1. Transformation 'A' is disabled
2. Transformation 'A' is enabled
3. Transformation 'A' is disabled

Given that all 3 runs uses the same cluster of Kafka brokers:-

1. If EOS is enabled, will EOS guarantee exist across all the 3 runs ?
2. If EOS is not enabled, Is there a case which may cause message loss( Failed to provide even at least once)?

The topology code to get better understanding of what I am trying to do:-

```
KStream<String, Cab> kStream = getStreamsBuilder()
            .stream("topic_a", Consumed.with(keySerde, valueSerde))
            .transformValues(() -> transformer1)
            .transformValues(() -> transformer2, "stateStore_a")
            .flatMapValues(events -> events);

    mayBeEnrichAgain(kStream, keySerde, valueSerde)
            .selectKey((ignored, event) -> event.getAnotherId())
            .through(INTERMEDIATE_TOPIC_2, Produced.with(keySerde, valueSerde)) //this repartitioning will always be there
            .transformValues(() -> transformer3, "stateStore_b")
            .to(txStreamsConfig.getAlertTopic(), Produced.with(keySerde, valueSerde));




private <E extends Cab> KStream<String, E> mayBeEnrichAgain(final KStream<String, E> kStream,
        final Serde<String> keySerde,
        final Serde<E> valueSerde) {

    if(enrichmentEnabled){ //repartitioning is configurable
            return kStream.selectKey((ignored, event) -> event.id())
                    .through(INTERMEDIATE_TOPIC_1, Produced.with(keySerde, valueSerde))
                    .transformValues(enricher1)
                    .transformValues(enricher2);
    }
    else{
            return kStream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply change the topology without potentially breaking it.

Hard to say in general if inserting the through-topic will break the application in the first place.

If it does not break, you might "loose" data when we remove the topic, as some unprocessed data might still be in this topic and after removing the topic, the topology would not read those data.

In general, you should reset an application cleanly or use a new `application.id` if you upgrade your app to a newer version that changes the structure of the topology.

Comment: What happens to my application state(all state store) when I change the application.id ? I will lose the state , is it?

Comment: Yes. If you change the application id, the new application starts with an empty state. (It cannot know that there was any old state -- it's like starting a second new application. The relationship between both is unknown.)

Comment: Doesn’t it means you can never upgrade the app which uses any sort of state. One way you can loose data(from intermediate topic) other looses state completely.

Comment: Depends... If you fix minor things or change minor things you can. As long as the structure of your topology doesn't change it's not a problem (eg, change a filter predicate). It's also possible (but hard to get right) to manually migrate state -- it's a know issues and we plan to address it in the future. Right now, the best thing to do is to run the new version in parallel an let it reprocess all data from the input topic to build up it's own state. After the new version caught up, you can switch over to it and stop the older version afterwards.